# One Windows Service to Start Multiple Windows Service

Tags: c#-4.0, service, windows-services

How i can create multiple Windows Service inside one Windows Service.
Suppose my class library name is WindowsService in side this i want to create two windows service abc and xyz. Now when i build this service i will get WindowsService.exe but i want to use abc service. How i can do that ?

I tried adding two services inside one service. but one get only Windowsservice.exe , how i can trigger two other service defined under it.

I need one service to start multiple services.
Thanks.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking.  Starting services doesn't have anything to do with the executable.  You start services using the `sc` command line tool or the Services administrative tool, or you can configure them to automatically start when the system boots.  Did you actually want to know how to install the services?

Comment: I mean to say i have one Windows Service inside that can i put multiple windows services and how i will differentiate which service to invoke as it will have only one Parent.exe do i need to install this Parent.exe. but this has two more windows services how to differntaire or invoke them one by one when needed ?

Comment: Each service has its own ServiceMain() function inside the executable, and the service control manager calls the one that belongs to the particular service that it has been asked to start.  The .NET library takes care of all this for you.